# What type of snake is this?

Tags: pest

Not 100% this is the right place to ask, but... since I was working on my shed and found this little guy, figured it would fit best in Home Improvement...

Anyways... I'm taking my shed apart (since it's already falling apart and I want to re-build it) and I found this little guy. Anyone know what kind of snake this is? I'm in Southern Delaware:

[image: Snake 1]

[image: Snake 2]

[image: Snake 3]

Comment: Whatever he is, it looks like he's recently eaten!

Comment: Is there a picture of the head, need some close ups of the eyes and nose areas and the under side.

Comment: That was a close as I was getting lol. Only reason I caught it was because it was above a spot I could put a can to knock him in. he's gone now :)

Comment: I expected to see a plumbing snake!  Don't use this one to clean out your drains, it will not make him happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the underside is white or lighter, its a black rat snake. This could could be a black king snake, but it would be weird. My money is with black rat snake or eastern rat snake. This snake is not venomous.

It matches the pattern and has white inbetween the scales, so I believe it to inbetween youth and adult phases. This decribes the faint white pattern.

I would let it go, it's obviously busy keeping other pests from staying around.

Comment: Yeah... no white underneath that I saw. Family wants it "far away" so I let it go in some woods a few miles away :)

Comment: +1, not a poisonous snake. Delaware's poisonous ones are timber rattlesnakes and copperheads, and this guy doesn't look like either.

Comment: Yeah... I don't see a resemblance to either. Good to know.

Comment: Agree that it's a black rat snake, esp. because of the extra body ripples.